# sparse matrix multiplication

Tags: performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

Say I have a sparse matrix $M$ with $\sim 50.000 .000$ non zero elements.

What is the fastest way to make operations such as :

$$M^k X$$

where $X$ is a given vector.

Is the operation  $MX$ parallelizable for example ? I have access to some kind of computing cluster and was wondering if I could make use of it ?

Comment: The 3 argument form of `MatrixPower` does exactly this operation. I don't know if there is a faster way, but I would guess not.

Comment: Do you really need $M^k\cdot X$ or do you ultimately calculate some other quantity from these powers?

Comment: Hum, actually I calculate $MX$ then I renormalize X, so that $X'=\frac{X}{||X||}$ then again MX', etc....

Comment: Are you by chance doing an [Arnoldi iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration) to find eigenvalues (specifically the largest one) and associated eigenvectors? If yes, then it will be much more effective to use the [built-in eigensystem algorithm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigensystem.html) with the Method->"Arnoldi" option, which is based on [ARPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPACK).